# replace a string in url in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to redirect `www.hostname.com/some path/?cpao=12` to `www.hostname.com/some path/?kmas=12`.

Essentially replacing the word `cpao` with `kmas` and keeping everything else the same.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cpao=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?kmas=%1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^hostname.com/somepath/\?cpao([0-9]+)$ hostname.com/somepath/\?kmas=$1
```

you use regex in htaccess $1 is the numbers that was catched in group 1

Comment: Thank you! How would I extrapolate it to be so be it any path i always want cpao substituted with kmas. substitute the string cpao with kmas.  Would it be possible to have all that captured in one rewrite rule or should I do more than one?

Comment: Yes, as I said it uses regex so you can use this to capture a lower caps path ([a-z]+) replace this with somepath

Comment: It won't work because RewriteRule only matches REQUEST_URI after stripping leading slash.

Comment: I forgot this Thank you @anubhava